# Caret - creating stratified data sets based on several variables

Tags: r, r-caret

In the R package caret, can we create stratified training and test sets based on several variables using the function createDataPartition() (or createFolds() for cross-validation)?

Here is an example for one variable:

```
#2/3rds for training
library(caret)
inTrain = createDataPartition(df$yourFactor, p = 2/3, list = FALSE)
dfTrain=df[inTrain,]
dfTest=df[-inTrain,]
```

In the code above the training and test sets are stratified by 'df$yourFactor'. But is it possible to stratify using several variables (e.g. 'df$yourFactor' and 'df$yourFactor2')? The following code seems to work but I don't know if it is correct:

```
inTrain = createDataPartition(df$yourFactor, df$yourFactor2, p = 2/3, list = FALSE)
```

Comment: The goal of creating those "stratified datasets" is to split the data along the outcome variable. Unless you're trying to get the outcome of two variables, I don't know if this would be a good idea.

Comment: have u checked in MLR package ?

Comment: @NelsonGon, that is not always the goal. There are other things one might want to stratify on. For example, I don't want my test set to be fundamentally different than my train set, such as having all very young people, while my train set has uniformly distributed ages, including young people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly simple if you use the `tidyverse`.

For example:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% #create row number if you dont have one
  select(n, everything()) # put 'n' at the front of the dataset
train <- df %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>% #any number of variables you wish to partition by proportionally
  sample_frac(.7) # '.7' is the proportion of the original df you wish to sample
test <- anti_join(df, train) # creates test dataframe with those observations not in 'train.'
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: very practical and tidy ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar to set seed with this method?

Comment: anti_join() is a performance black hole. Consider trying `test <- df[-train$n,]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.frame(yourFactor = sample(1:5,n,TRUE), 
                yourFactor2 = rbinom(n,1,.5),
                yourFactor3 = rbinom(n,1,.7))
```

### stratum indicator

```
d$group <- interaction(d[, c('yourFactor', 'yourFactor2')])
```

### sample selection

```
indices <- tapply(1:nrow(d), d$group, sample, 30 )
```

### obtain subsample

```
subsampd <- d[unlist(indices, use.names = FALSE), ]
```

what this does is make a size 30 random stratified sample on every combination of `yourFactor` and `yourFactor2`.